# Get text between HTML tags

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, preg-match

Ok, This is a pretty basic question im sure but im new to PHP and haven't been able to figure it out. The input string is $data im trying to continue to pull and only use the first match. Is the below incorrect? This may not even be the best way to perform the action, im just trying to pull the contents in between two html tags (first set found) and discard the rest of the data. I know there are similar questions, ive read them all, my question is a mix, if theres a better way to do this and how i can define the match as the new input for the rest of the remaining code. If i change $matches to $data2 and use it from there on out it returns errors.

```
preg_match('/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/s', $data, $matches);
```

Comment: -1 for not searching before asking. There is an entry in the [tag wiki for that](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) and the very [first question in the FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=faq&pagesize=50) is [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html). And that's in addition to the [hundreds of question all asking the same lame question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+html+[php]) almost each and every day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using regular expressions is generally a good idea for your problem.

When you look at http://php.net/preg_match you see that $matches will be an array, since there may be more than one match. Try

```
print_r($matches);
```

to get an idea of how the result looks, and then pick the right index.

EDIT:

If there is a match, then you can get the text extracted between the parenthesis-group with

```
print($matches[1]);
```

If you had more than one parenthesis-group they would be numbered 2, 3 etc. You should also consider the case when there is no match, in which case the array will have the size of 0.

Comment: I've used that to make sure it correctly pulls the tags, i think my issue is defining the 1st returned value/array as the input string for the remained of the code... ?

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful. Do you know how i would call the output as input for the next line of code though? If i use
`$matches = str_replace("Hello", "Hi", $matches);` it doesnt work, i guess the problem is i can successfully fetch and select the right array but i cant successfully apply any further code to it after its been pulled.

Comment: Just do:  $data = $matches[1];

Comment: I had tried that earlier with errors, perhaps it only works now after selecting a index as you suggested, thanks a million, it works perfect.

Answer (score 25):

Don't parse HTML via `preg_match`, use this PHP class instead:

### [The DOMDocument class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

**Example:**

```
<?php 

$html= "<p>hi</p>
<h1>H1 title</h1>
<h2>H2 title</h2>
<h3>H2 title</h3>";
 // a new dom object 
 $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
 // load the html into the object 
 $dom->loadHTML($html); 
 //discard white space 
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
 $hTwo= $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2'); // here u use your desired tag
 echo $hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue; 
 //will return "H2 title";
 ?>
```

[Reference](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Parse-HTML-With-PHP-And-DOM.html)

Comment: This only works if the HTML is reasonably wellformed - which of course it should be.

Comment: @Erik It's a myth that `DOM` can only parse (reasonably) well formed HTML.  `loadHTML()` uses libxml's [HTML parser module](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) and that is (quoting) *able to parse "real world" HTML, even if severely broken from a specification point of view.*

Comment: @erik, regular expressions are the hammer of the programmer's toolkit.  If your toolkit provides a more appropriate tool then you should use that instead.  In this case DOMDocument is that tool (also, I'm not the other Gordon, just to clear things up :) )

Comment: Is it really better to do this in the case of something as simple as getting the contents of an element or few? What are the domDocument overheads compared to a regex?

Comment: https://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Text-Between-Tags.html

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way::

```
$h1 = preg_replace('/<h1[^>]*?>([\\s\\S]*?)<\/h1>/',
'\\1', $h1);
```

This will Strip off or unwrap the TEXT from the `<H1></H1>` HTML Tags

Comment: It works well, thank you.